# qt style QPalette::windowText color reverts after application starts

Tags: c++, qt, styling, osx-mavericks

I've created a Qt application using a slightly modified version of the 'cleanlooks' style. I've tried setting the WindowText with the following code but the change doesn't stick. when I open the application it opens in the background with the correct text color, when I click the application and bring it to the foreground the text reverts to black and I cant work out why. does anybody know why this may be or how I should be setting the window text?

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QPalette>
#include <QtGui/QColor>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPalette p;

    p.setBrush(QPalette::WindowText, QColor(255,0,0));

    a.setStyle("cleanlooks");
    a.setPalette(p);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I'm using OSX 10.9 and Qt 4.8.6

---

**Update 1**

I tested the code on a windows 7 Machine running Qt 4.8.5 built from source and this problem did not occur. I't seems to be a problem with either MacOS 10.9 or Qt 4.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your answer is already reported (and confirmed) as a QT bug ([QTBUG-32067](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32067)).

> While we have never really supported custom palette roles for most of
>   QMacStyle I think we should allow setting a custom palette on it even
>   if it breaks for some cases. [Jens comment on QTBUG-32067](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32067?focusedCommentId=214471&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-214471)

Answer (score 0):

See [documentation notes of QApplication::setpalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setPalette).

> **Note**: Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for
>   instance, if they make use of native theme engines. This is the case
>   for the Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Mac OS X styles.

So you can can check this by running application with different style, by starting your application from shell like this:

```
applicationToRun -style=windows
```

Or by using other styles, docs says: motif, windows and platinum, but this depends on installed Qt and its plugins.

---

**Edit:** ups I didn't noticed that you are setting style by code. Anyway verify that style you are enforcing is supported by Qt on current machine, check if `a.setStyle("cleanlooks");` returns a valid style (on errors it returns null). I would try all styles (list available form `QStyleFactory::keys()`).

Comment: I've checked and the style is indeed available on both platforms it just seems that the implementation is either different or broken on this version of osx/Qt